# Construction of Peltier tiles

Tags: semiconductors, peltier, electricity

I'm learning about the construction of Peltier tiles from Wikpedia. However, some of the statements in the article are not at all clear.

[image]
*[Here's the extract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling#Construction):*

> Two unique semiconductors, one n-type and one p-type, are used because
>   they need to have different electron densities. The semiconductors are
>   placed thermally in parallel to each other and electrically in series
>   and then joined with a thermally conducting plate on each side. When a
>   voltage is applied to the free ends of the two semiconductors there is
>   a flow of DC current across the junction of the semiconductors causing
>   a temperature difference. The side with the cooling plate absorbs heat
>   which is then moved to the other side of the device where the heat
>   sink is. Thermoelectric Coolers, also abbreviated to TECs are
>   typically connected side by side and sandwiched between two ceramic
>   plates. The cooling ability of the total unit is then proportional to
>   the number of TECs in it.

- What does "**thermally in parallel to each other and electrically in series**" mean for semiconductors? Also, why should they be arranged in this fashion?
- Why does flow of DC current across the junction of semiconductors cause a temperature difference? Which "junction" are they talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your diagram, it shows the N and P semiconductors connected in pairs (look at the lower layer - the "interconnect"). So the electrical path is in series : the sum of the junctions to work on probably 12v.

And the heat transfer is through all the N and P junctions ie in parallel.

Comment: As to "why?" the temperature difference occurs - that **IS** the Peltier effect and will be covered in any serious commentary on the subject.